# Removing Old Application from Apple Store to Upload a new with same name?

Tags: iphone, ios4

i have had an application on Apple App Store for quite some time now with latest version reaching upto 3.3. i was wondering with further changes increasing the version number wont look good for new and old users alike.. Can i remove this application from sale and upload a new App with same name and functionality with version 1.0 ??

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not, but you might end up confusing customers if you do that.

Comment: Version numbers should never go down.  It's confusing for the user and for you when someone contacts you with a problem and you can't figure out if this is a new 1.0 or the original 1.0.
Go ahead and increase your version.  Everyone does it.  Apple is at 10.7.1 and 4.3.1.  It just shows you're responsive and are continuing to work on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with increasing the version number? That just tells people that you support your app and that you're continuing to improve it with new features and bug fixes. If you don't want the number to grow too large, just use a smaller increment for each new release.

Answer (score 1):

Apple prevents you from setting the version number to the same or a lower number in a subsequent release. And you can't reuse a bundle identifier. So, in short, to go back to version 1 you'd have to pretend you were making an entirely *different* application (especially with In-App Purchases, you'd have to re-enter all of that information on the new app).

Then, in an update for your old app (its final update), notify your users of the old application that they need to remove this version totally **AFTER** they install a new version and do a settings migration (ideally you'd want to have a migration process which takes data from your old installed app and copies it into the new one).

You can try the above. But I think Apple would probably take issue with you doing it. The best thing to do though is what @Caleb is saying, just start using a third version number (revision, like 3.3.1, 3.3.2, etc). Or you can always switch to the new 'marketing-focused' versioning of Mozilla products and Google Chrome: release version 4 now and version 5 in a few months' time, etc. A single version number looks less "complicated" and "technical" to the end user.